# Married by Islam but husband divorced me by saying it in English

Tags: talaq, english

Hi me and my husband are married by Islam if he says in English 3 times he divorces me and puts my name at the end when he says I divorce you and then my name dose that mean we are divorced

Comment: Evan tho when we got married he agreed in his language he divorced me in English so kinda confused as to if we are divorced

Comment: we was having a very bad argument when he said it in english

Answer (score 3):

```
             In the name of Allah, the most compassionate, the most merciful
```

In regarding to your question that asked

> married by islam but hsband divorced me by saying it in english

The Siqah (specific phrase or sentence which is recited for talaq or divorce), ought to be recited in Arabic. On the other hand, attendance (hearing the mentioned phrase) of two Aadel (Just) men is considered as another condition of Talaq (divorce). Therefore, by paying heed to what you said, it can be inferred that your divorce is not counted as a complete right divorce.

---

**Reference:**

[www.islamquest.net](http://www.islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa29299)

Answer (score 1):

A marriage contract can be terminated in any language. One only has to make the decision and let it be known as per the norms of the society. Institution of marriage has existed in all societies and probably predates even the Arabic language. Therefore the requirement that a specific word has to be said and that too in a specific language, is mere gibberish/nonsense.

As per Quran, only a single divorce is possible in one sitting. It doesn't matter if the words are uttered more than once. If the couple wants to reconcile, then they can start living together again (provided they do so within a specific timeframe otherwise they have to remarry). If they don't want to reconcile, then this single divorce may also be taken as final.